# Why does the SQL query order changes if I name my table?

Tags: sql

one question:

When executing the standard SQL query what is the difference between those two? because I get different ordering:

1. `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM database.table order by col2`
2. `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM database.table L order by col2` (naming it L)

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the difference.

Comment: L is just an alias for the table name

Comment: There is no difference. Please demonstrate the different ordering using DB<>Fiddle.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Answer (score 1):

L is just an alias for the table.
In that query it has no purpose.

The aliasname won't make a difference to the order definded by the ORDER BY clause.
At most, col2 isn't unique, and running either query on different times might change the order of col1, col3.

It's more useful when joining several tables that have some column names in common.

For example.

```
SELECT 
 long_winded_table_name_full_of_stuff.id,
 long_winded_table_name_full_of_stuff.name as name1,
 other_table_not_named_by_a_golfcoder.name as name2
FROM long_winded_table_name_full_of_stuff
LEFT JOIN other_table_not_named_by_a_golfcoder
ON other_table_not_named_by_a_golfcoder.fk_id = long_winded_table_name_full_of_stuff.id
```

By using aliases you can shorten that.

```
SELECT
 s.id,
 s.name as name1,
 other.name as name2
FROM long_winded_table_name_full_of_stuff AS s
LEFT JOIN other_table_not_named_by_a_golfcoder AS other
ON other.fk_id = s.id
```

It help to increase readability.
So people use aliases in their queries, even if the tables don't have column names in common.

Comment: curious why you deleted your good answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441318/how-do-we-declare-a-variable-inside-of-a-table-valued-function

Comment: @AlexGordon They were making an argument about how that method with the table variable doesn't help performance. So that answer would have gotten downvotes anyway. I figured you had enough reputation to see that answer. ;) Besides, you have an alternative. Cross applying to values.  Personally, I also think that method should be kept for small stuff. Not big reports.

Comment: thanks man i appreciate your insight

Answer (score 0):

> When executing the standard SQL query what is the difference between those two? because I get different ordering:

They are different queries, so they are more likely to get different query plans than if you ran the identical query twice, although that can happen too.

And if `col2` isn't unique, ordering by it doesn't force a complete ordering of the rows, and different query plans can produce different orderings.

If you need a stable ordering, like for a paging implementation, make sure the ORDER BY is unique.  Typically you just add the PK column(s) to the end of the ORDER BY.